# Getting GooglePay Payment Data from intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, capacitor, google-pay

I'm writing my first custom Capacitor plugin for my Ionic app - the plugin needs to present the user with a GooglePay screen where they will select their payment card, the plugin needs to then return to the Ionic app with the payment data.  I have almost got this working but I'm struggling with the final part - extracting the payment data from the intent.

My code is shown below.  When the handlePaymentActivityResult method runs I return the paymentData to my Ionic app as a JSObject with a key of "paymentToken" but what I see when I then display it is:

```
{"paymentToken";"com.google.android.gms.wallet.PaymentData@1e64707"}
```

this is obviously not correct - I would be expecting an encrypted paymentToken amongst other things.  What am I doing wrong?  (I'm not a Java or native Android developer - that might be obvious!)

```
@PluginMethod
    public void requestPayment(PluginCall call) {
        currentCall = call;

        if (activity == null) {
            call.reject("Activity is null");
            return;
        }

        String paymentDataRequestJsonString = """
                {
                    "apiVersion": 2,
                    "apiVersionMinor": 0,
                    "allowedPaymentMethods": [
                    {
                        "type": "CARD",
                        "parameters": {
                            "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
                            "allowedCardNetworks": ["VISA", "MASTERCARD"],
                            "billingAddressRequired": true,
                            "billingAddressParameters": {
                                "format": "FULL",
                                "phoneNumberRequired": true
                        }
                },
                    "tokenizationSpecification": {
                        "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
                            "parameters": {
                                "gateway": "barclayssmartpayadvance",
                                "gatewayMerchantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "transactionInfo": {
                "totalPrice": "10.00",
                "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
                 "currencyCode": "USD"
            },
            "merchantInfo": {
                "merchantId": "",
                "merchantName": "Example Merchant"
            }
        }""";

        try {
            JSONObject paymentDataRequestJson = new JSONObject(paymentDataRequestJsonString);
            PaymentDataRequest paymentDataRequest = PaymentDataRequest.fromJson(paymentDataRequestJson.toString());
            AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(
                paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest),
                activity,
                LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE
        );
            // Use the paymentDataRequest object as needed
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle the JSON parsing error
        }
    }

    private PaymentsClient createPaymentsClient(Activity activity) {
        Wallet.WalletOptions walletOptions = new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                .build();

        return Wallet.getPaymentsClient(activity, walletOptions);
    }

    public void handlePaymentActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.d("handlePaymentActivity", "PAYMENT");
                PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);

                    JSObject result = new JSObject();
                    result.put("paymentToken", paymentData);

                    // Resolve the stored plugin call with the payment token
                    if (currentCall != null) {
                        currentCall.resolve(result);
                        currentCall = null; // Reset the stored call
                    }

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.d("handlePaymentActivity", "CANCELLED");
                // Reject the stored plugin call
                if (currentCall != null) {
                    currentCall.reject("Payment canceled");
                    currentCall = null; // Reset the stored call
                }
            } else if (resultCode == AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR) {
                Log.d("handlePaymentActivity", "ERROR");
                // An error occurred during the payment process
                Status status = AutoResolveHelper.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                String errorMessage = status != null ? status.getStatusMessage() : "Unknown error occurred";

                // Reject the stored plugin call with the error message
                if (currentCall != null) {
                    currentCall.reject("Payment error: " + errorMessage);
                    currentCall = null; // Reset the stored call
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got it working - I had to change the code to PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);
                String token = paymentData.toJson();
                    JSObject result = new JSObject();
                    result.put("paymentToken", token);